How to add content security headers in Next.js which are configurable from cms side? where to add?
I want to add CSP headers with next.js from sitecore CMS. from where I will get data and I know I need to add that in middleware but how to add that from CMS side.
I tried this: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/content-security-policy
It is working fine for static case but how i can add it dynamically and how to get data from sitecore CMS?

In my recent project, I looked into this scenario I have two solution for this case with cons as well.
First, need to add header fields in sitecore cms.


Using middleware : You can refer this link:https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/content-security-policy

In this case, you need to simple call fetch API for graphQL call which helps to get data from sitecore cms.
and simple replace static headers with api response.
But the problem with this case is, for security reason we can't simply call this api in client side we need to call it through server call only and it will impact on costing part. also, on every request it will call that graphql api and then load page or call other api which also impact on performance.
So as per my point of view this is not better approach to use.

In next.config (Currently I am using it): We can also call graphQL call in next.config file so it will call one time when we build next.js project so it will not impact on performance and costing part.

but also this solution have cons like whenever we change csp header in sitecore cms side we need to redeploy whole next.js application.
because this solution once call api when we build it.
I added one corsHeaderPlugin plugin for next.config
const config = require('../../../temp/config');
const { GraphQLRequestClient } = require('@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-nextjs/graphql');

const keyValueOfHeader = {
  contentSecurityPolicy: process.env.DISABLE_CSP
    ? 'Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only'
    : 'Content-Security-Policy',
};
const getCorsHeaderData = async () => {
  try {
    const headerQuery = `query{
    homeItem: item(path: "{8555eeeee226C07A48-894C-46E2-B333-5CF629215C1A}", language: "en") {
      ... on HTTPHeaders{
        contentSecurityPolicy{
          value
        }
      }
    }
  }`;

    const graphQLClient = new GraphQLRequestClient(config.graphQLEndpoint, {
      apiKey: config.sitecoreApiKey,
    });
    const result = await graphQLClient.request(headerQuery, {
      language: 'en',
    });
    let headerData = [];
    if (result?.homeItem && Object.keys(result?.homeItem)?.length > 0) {
      Object.keys(result?.homeItem)?.forEach((key) => {
        if (result?.homeItem?.[key]?.value) {
          headerData.push({
            key: keyValueOfHeader?.[key],
            value: result?.homeItem?.[key]?.value?.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ').trim(),
          });
        }
      });
    }
    return headerData;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('err', err);
  }
};

const getOtherHeader = () => [
  {
    source: '/_next/:path*',
    headers: [
      {
        key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
        value: config.sitecoreApiHost.replace(/\/$/, ''),
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    source: '/api/:path*',
    headers: [
      {
        key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
        value: config.sitecoreApiHost.replace(/\/$/, ''),
      },
      {
        key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
        value: 'GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST',
      },
      {
        key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
        value: 'Content-Type',
      },
    ],
  },
];
/**
 * @param {import('next').NextConfig} nextConfig
 */
const corsHeaderPlugin = (nextConfig = {}) => {
  if (!config.sitecoreApiHost) {
    return Object.assign({}, nextConfig, {
      async headers() {
        const corsHeaders = await getCorsHeaderData();
        const headers =
          corsHeaders?.length > 0
            ? [
                {
                  source: '/(.*)',
                  headers: corsHeaders,
                },
              ]
            : [];
        return headers;
      },
    });
  }
  return Object.assign({}, nextConfig, {
    async headers() {
      const corsHeaders = await getCorsHeaderData();
      const headers =
        corsHeaders?.length > 0
          ? [
              {
                source: '/(.*)',
                headers: corsHeaders,
              },
              ...getOtherHeader(),
            ]
          : getOtherHeader();
      return headers;
    },
  });
};

module.exports = corsHeaderPlugin;

Which solution is better?: According to me second solution it better with not impact on performance and costing if we want it from sitecore CMS side as we are not going to frequently change headers so if we change it like once in month or twice in a month then it is okay to redeploy next.js application.

Thank you for quick reply, I will try and let you know
